# how do i change the font in sublime text search bar / CTRL+ P key

Tags: sublimetext3

[image]

I want to change the font of the search bar and also the results there, because I can't see it clearly

Comment: There is a way to change this by changing a font size, but you will need to open some `.sublime_package` files of Sublime Text and configure _quick panel_ . There is package to open and edit those kind of packages. I think you need to find `Default.sublime_package`, but it could be some other `.sublime_package` file.

Comment: [
 {
  "class": "sidebar_label",
  "color": [0, 0, 0],
  "font.bold": false,
  "font.size": 11.3,
  "font.face" : "Menlo",
 },
],

I added like that in my Default.sublime theme I just don't know the entry for the class..

Comment: I think you should search for _command pallete_ or _quick panel_ ? Sidebar represent a part of sublime where it lists a project or open files.

Comment: @DinkoPehar,can u assiste me?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. I tried it a little bit, there are some infos online, but it's very hard and hacky to open these files. Your question is very good, offer a bounty if you don't find a proper solution. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question still hanging so I installed Sublime on Debian to try to configure it.

First of all, you can read how to customize Sublime at [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html). And the part of interface you want to configure is called [quick_panel](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html#elements-quick_panel), specifically class **quick_panel_label**.

At the end of theme configuration page, there is an example of [customization file](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html#customization).

I don't know what theme are you using, but if you are using *Default* theme, you should create new file called `Default.sublime-theme` and place it in `Packages/User/`. You can quickly find that path by menu of sublime, `Preferences -> Browse packages...` .

Content of `Default.sublime-theme` should be:

```
[
    {
        "class": "quick_panel_label",
        "font.size": 25
    }
]
```

where `font.size` represent font size of menu you are trying to customize.

*P.S.*

If you don't know the name of the file your theme is using, from menu choose `Preferences -> Theme...` and all themes should be listed with their `.sublime-theme` file.

For example, I customized *Arc Dark* theme.

[image: Sublime Text quick panel customization]

I hope this works for you.

Comment: How about also the text of the search bar not the resultsof what I type ?